# How to pass two-dimensional array of structures to function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, memory, struct

There is a two-dimensional array of structures, I am passing an array pointer to a function:

```
result.capabilities = (Capabilities **)malloc(sizeof(Capabilities *)*6);
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
    result.capabilities[i] = (Capabilities *)malloc(sizeof(Capabilities)*8);
}
init_capabilities(&result.capabilities);
```

Function call cause an error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x003c10f9 in solution.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xfdfdfdfd.

Here is my function:

```
void init_capabilities(Capabilities ***capabilities) {
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
            printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
            capabilities[i][j]->room_capabilities = new RoomCapability[rooms_count];
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that the dimension of the array `capabilities` - 6x8. It turned out that 1x6.
An hour headache because of this. Show you how to change the type of argument or how to refer to elements of my array, so that everything fell into place?

Comment: Is this C or C++?  Because I think I can help you if you're writing in C++ using `new` instead of `malloc()` which C++ provides (which gives you much cleaner, straightforward syntax and is safer than `malloc()` IIRC).

Comment: This is really bad C/C++ mix code. And when I say bad, I *mean* it. Don't use `malloc` in C++. Use references in C++ whenever possible and feasable.

Comment: Don't be a [three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer). That only brings pain.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing your pointer-to-pointer-to-Capabilities by pointer. That is why you have three asterisks instead of two.

Try this:

```
void init_capabilities(Capabilities ***capabilities) {
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
            printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
            // Note: extra dereference:
            (*capabilities)[i][j].room_capabilities = new RoomCapability[rooms_count];
        }
    }
}
```

**Or** this:

```
result.capabilities = (Capabilities **)malloc(sizeof(Capabilities *)*6);
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
    result.capabilities[i] = (Capabilities *)malloc(sizeof(Capabilities)*8);
}
init_capabilities(result.capabilities); // Note NO address-of operator

// Note: two stars, not three
void init_capabilities(Capabilities **capabilities) {
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
            printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
            capabilities[i][j].room_capabilities = new RoomCapability[rooms_count];
        }
    }
}
```

Or, since you are coding in C++, not C:

```
// Assuming that result.capabilities and Capabilties::room_capabilities are declared
// vectors of the appropriate types ...
result.capabilities = std::vector<std::vector<Capabilities> >(std::vector<Capabilities>(8),6);
init_capabilities(result.capabilities);

void init_capabilities(std::vector<std::vector<Capabilities>& capabilities) {
    for(int i=0;i<capabilities.size();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<capabilties[i].size();j++){
            printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
            capabilities[i][j].room_capabilities.resize(rooms_count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In `init_capabilities`, shouldn't it be `.` instead of `->`?

Answer (score 1):

Declare

```
void init_capabilities(Capabilities ***capabilities)
```

as

```
void init_capabilities(Capabilities **capabilities)
```

and call by

```
init_capabilities(result.capabilities);
```

You just need to pass the pointer to your array structure, not a pointer to the pointer of your array structure.

**Edit**:  And as others have pointed out, if you're going to use C++ you should really be using `new` as in:

```
result.capabilities = new (Capabilities *)[6];
for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
  result.capabilities[i] = new Capabilities[8];
}
init_capabilities(result.capabilities);
```

...

```
void init_capabilities(Capabilities **capabilities) {
  for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<8;j++) {
      capabilities[i][j].room_capabilities = new RoomCapability[rooms_count];
    }
  }
}
```

And don't forget to use `delete[]`.  Better yet, do as Rob suggests and use the pre-defined C++ containers to handle this sort of thing.  But if you really want to use unsafe pointers, what I have above should get it done for you.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a whole host of problems here:

1. You allocate space for each individual Capability, then create a
   new one, turning the allocated space into garbage
2. You treat
   capabilities as a 2d array, when it is actually an array of pointers
   to arrays
3. You pass the address of this overall array, but do
   nothing to deference it in the function

Until you get straight what you're trying to do, HOW to do it will have to wait.